# Variable Tipo Clase_Java

Tags: java, clase

He empezado hace poco a aprender a programar utilizando Java.

Me he encontrado el siguiente fragmento de código :

```
public class Alumno {

private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String telefono;

//métodos

}

public boolean valida(Alumno alumno) {

String nombre = alumno.getNombre(); 
char primeraLetra = nombre.charAt(0);
char ultimaLetra = nombre.charAt(nombre.length() - 1)

}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que significa en el método valida: (Alumno alumno).¿Se utiliza la clase como identificador de tipo de variable?

Comment: Si, la Clase es un tipo de Objeto. Una clase define como será un objeto (es un análogo a un molde) y el objeto es una instancia de la Clase es creado cuando se realiza un `new`. En esa función dice que recibirá como argumento un objeto del tipo `Alumno`

Comment: el parámetro alumno es un objeto de la clase Alumno el cual dependiendo del constructor de la propia clase tendrá como atributo un nombre apellido y teléfono, para acceder a estos atributos los realizas con el uso de getter por ejemplo tu método valida usa getNombre()

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto no es una red social, por favor aprende como funciona el sitio leyendo los links que te pase

Answer (score 2):

Está claramente explicado en la Especificación del Lenguaje, [apartado **8.4.1. Formal Parameters**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1):

> The formal parameters of a method or constructor, if any, are
> specified by a list of comma-separated parameter specifiers. Each
> parameter specifier consists of a type (optionally preceded by the
> final modifier and/or one or more annotations) and an identifier
> (optionally followed by brackets) that specifies the name of the
> parameter.
>
> If a method or constructor has no formal parameters, and no receiver
> parameter, then an empty pair of parentheses appears in the
> declaration of the method or constructor.
>
> ---
>
> Los parámetros formales de un método o constructor, si los hay, se
> especifican mediante una lista de especificadores de parámetros
> separados por comas. Cada especificador de parámetro consta de un tipo
> (opcionalmente precedido por el modificador final y/o una o más
> anotaciones) y un identificador (opcionalmente seguido por corchetes)
> que especifica el nombre del parámetro.
>
> Si un método o constructor no tiene parámetros formales ni parámetros
> de receptor, aparece un par de paréntesis vacíos en la declaración del
> método o constructor.

En el caso que expones:

```
public boolean valida(Alumno alumno) {
    String nombre = alumno.getNombre(); 
    char primeraLetra = nombre.charAt(0);
    char ultimaLetra = nombre.charAt(nombre.length() - 1)
}
```

`Alumno` es el **tipo**, y `alumno` es el **identificador**.

Imaginemos que además de un parámetro del tipo `Alumno` el método requiera un entero, para obtener un valor dinámico, la declaración del método podría hacerse así:

```
public boolean valida(Alumno alumno, int anyPosition) {
    String nombre = alumno.getNombre();
    char anyCharacter = nombre.charAt(anyPosition); 
    char primeraLetra = nombre.charAt(0);
    char ultimaLetra = nombre.charAt(nombre.length() - 1)
}
```

Aquí, `int` es el **tipo** y `anyPosition` es el **identificador** como explica la Especificación.

Answer (score 0):

Así es, en la función valida tu envías una variable como parámetro de entrada.

Con la particularidad de que la variable que estas enviando en lugar de ser una Variable de tipo String o de tipo Integer, es una variable de tipo Alumno que tiene las propiedades que has definido arriba en la clase.

(Atributo nombre, atributo apellido y atributo teléfono).

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que no entiendo es que significa en el método valida: (Alumno
> alumno).¿Se utiliza la clase como identificador de tipo de variable?

En este caso, `Alumno` es el tipo, y `alumno` es el identificador, tu método `valida()` indica que recibirá una variable de tipo `Alumno` llamada `alumno`

```
public static boolean valida(Alumno alumno) {
  String nombre = alumno.getNombre(); 
  char primeraLetra = nombre.charAt(0);
  char ultimaLetra = nombre.charAt(nombre.length() - 1)
  return true;
}
```

Por ejemplo, de acuerdo a tu clase `Alumno` :

```
public class Alumno {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String telefono;
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

}
```

Se instancia y se envía a tu método valida() el cual retornará un valor tipo boolean:

```
//Crea objeto.
Alumno alumno = new Alumno();
//define valores a propiedades
alumno.setNombre("JJ");
alumno.setNombre("Roldan");
alumno.setTelefono("55-53065555");

//Envia objeto a método valida.
boolean resultado = valida(alumno);

System.out.println("El resultado es: " +resultado);
```